# How do I add a directory to a repository?

Tags: git, github, directory, repository

So this is the situation: 
I'm using VS-Code and the integrated terminal, if that matters.

```
git clone foo
```

Alright good.
Now I add a document and save it.

```
git add . 
git commit -m "COmment what i did"
git push origin master
```

works like a charm

---

Now I'm working on a *.md file* 
In said file i want to add pictures. 
I want to refer to those like:

```
./Images/NameOfThePicture.jpg
```

Using the integrated Terminal in VSC I used:

```
mkdir Images
```

So now there is ./src/Documentation/Images 
Great!

---

But when I now do

```
git add ./Images
git commit -m "foo"
git push origin master
```

The ./Images directory simply isn't there.

---

So what I'm looking for is something like

```
git add ./Images
git commit -m "foo"
git push origin master
```

IT CAN'T BE THAT HARD, CAN IT?!

---

I did google a ton of stuff, but simply didn't find an answer I understood right off the bat.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're going to add things into the direcory, all you need to do is add the file within that directory:

```
git add ./Images/NameOfThePicture.jpg
git commit -m "Write a meaningful commit message."
git push origin master
```

As Matthieu Brucher said above, a blank folder doesn't have a diff, so it's difficult to add one, and in this case it's not necessary. If you do write an application that requires a blank folder to exist, there are workarounds, but most of them preclude you from then having anything in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add a folder to git, as a folder doesn't have a diff. 
If you add files inside the folder, then the folder will be created when the repo is checked out.

Comment: Just to add to Matthieu's answer, git does not track directories. period. If a directory is empty, to git, it's as if it didn't exist at all. The easiest thing you can do is add a README file so that you explain what's going on in there and so the directory will magically show up.